# How correct spark glue writes bitint into orc format?

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

Consider a code

```
//read some csv table to dynamic frame like that:
val frame = glueContext
  .getCatalogSource(database = "my_database", tableName = "my_table")
  .getDynamicFrame()
//apply some mapping:
val mapped = frame.applyMapping(Seq("biging_col", "string", "biging_col", "bigint"))
//write to orc format:
glueContext.getSinkWithFormat(
  connectionType = "s3",
  options = JsonOptions(Map("path" -> "some_out_path", "partitionKeys" -> List("my_date"))),
format = "orc").writeDynamicFrame(mapped)
```

Everythings "works" (e.g. no failing errors), but:

1. Spark [does not have](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/package-summary.html) any `BigInteger` types, just [DecimalType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DecimalType.html) but "writing" integrals with `.0` precision is not good. (Btw is it safe to use thistype with care that is wiil not be coverted to `double` type somewhere?)
2. orc also [does not have](https://orc.apache.org/docs/types.html) any `BigInteger` types, even there is no `Decimal` type.

So what is the magic is going on when I have to write some `bigint` column from `csv` to `orc` with spark and aws glue mapping apply? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: In Spark `bigint` is synonymous with `LongType`.

Comment: And the docs that you linked for ORC say `bigint (64 bit)` is present